# Помогите решить проблему с Spring Security

Tags: spring, java-ee, maven, spring-security

Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]

Вчера всё работало и запускалось, сегодня ковырял только .jsp и внезапно начало выплёвывать ошибку.
Перепробовал множество решений выдаваемых в Гугле, ничего не помогает.
Заранее благодарен за помощь.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:security.xml]
>   Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]

кусок pom.xml

4.0.3.RELEASE

```
            <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

                    <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  
xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.0">
<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:spring-context.xml" /> 
<import resource="classpath:security.xml" />

<context:component-scan base-package="by.vonotirah.auctionProject.webApp" />
```

security.xml

```
<beans:beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="by.vonotirah.auctionProject" />
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/admin" />
</http>
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl" >
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это исключение говорит о том, что `NamespaceHandler` не может найти XSD схему, которую вы объявили в вашем конфигурационном файле.

Поиск в первую очередь выполняется в classpath приложения, т.е. в директории `/WEB-INF/lib`. Если вы зайдете в нее, и откроете файл `spring-security-config-${spring.version}.jar`, то в директории `/META-INF` лежит файл `spring.schemas`, который содержит маппинги URL на локальные файлы:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.2.xsd
```

А в каталоге `org/springframework/security/config` в том же jar, соответственно, лежат сами файлы. Это относится и к другим модулям Spring.

Вопрос, почему spring не находит XSD, может иметь различные решения:

- ошибка в синтаксисе конфигурационного файла;
- отсутствие библиотеки `spring-security-config` в classpath приложения;
- для ускорения старта приложения сервлет-контейнеры [позволяют](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#Exclude_JARs_from_scanning) [исключать](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-webapps.html#webapp-context-attributes) JAR файлы из сканнера;

У вас, например, объявлено, что Spring Security должен иметь ту жу версию, что и Spring MVC. Что не есть хорошо, поскольку обычно эти версии отличаются.

Если собираете проект maven'ом, выполните `mvn clean package` и начните проверять по порядку.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать. А какие версии Spring MVC и Spring Security лучше использовать ?

Comment: Если по каким-либо причинам не интересует конкретная версия библиотеки, то зайдите на [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/), выполните поиск по artifactId и возьмите последнюю. Для Spring берите stable, т.е. те что оканчиваются на RELEASE.

Comment: В общем я так и не понял в чём проблема, но всё заработало.
Пока ждал тут ответа, ничего не делал, после вашего ответа перезапустил TomCat и он вывалил совершенно другую ошибку (org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webApp]]).
Перезагрузился, запустил по новой и всё заработало =\

Вчера у меня тоже всё работало без проблем, ошибка начала вылетать только сегодня, учитывая что я конфигурации никакие не менял...просто в jsp ковырялся.